# Access a text file inside Android application from my Robotium based test application

Tags: android

I have a text file on my device placed at /data/data/com.abc.def/files with MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE and MODE_WORLD_READABLE permissions. I want to access this file from my Android test application written in Robotium(test.apk). After I access it, I want to parse this and calculate some results based on the data present on this file. The new result will be written to new file created using test application (test.apk). Also, I am signing the test app with signature compatible with application being tested. 
Please let me know how can I access this file? What modifications I need to make to my Android manifest file of test app. Please give some useful link.

Thanks
Kunal